# How to insert document page number in a header with word addin?

Tags: ms-word, office-js, office-addins, word-addins

I know how to insert footer and header, but I wonder how can I insert page number with with my word addin?

```
'Word.run(function (context) {
 var mySections = context.document.sections;
 context.load(mySections, 'body/style');
 return context.sync().then(function () {var myFooter = 
   mySections.items[0].getFooter("primary");
   myFooter.insertParagraph(footerText.value, "End");
                return context.sync().then(function () {
                    console.log("Added a footer to the first section.");
                });
            });

'
```

Comment: Page numbers in Word documents are field codes. Currently, the Office JS APIs for Word don't support field codes, except by reading/writing OOXML. You might want to see these two User Voice topics https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/16473235-adding-field-codes-for-word-using-word-javascript and https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/33776575-add-support-to-read-field-codes-in-the-document-us

Comment: Thank you @Cindy Meister for your reply. I tried to look into the OOXML and I found 3 footer 3 header xml files, but still can't find the page number info. Could you explain more how can I get the info from the OOXML? Also, I tried to insert content control to document's primary header, then I was thinking I can count the content control objects' number to determine header number then altimately the page number, but the contentcontrol.items.length result has alway been 1...Any idea why?

Comment: Figurerd it out how the header/footer works. There's only one header per section. Even though it renders on every page, it's still the same header object. Therefore no matter how many pages are in the section, there will be only one content control.

Comment: That is correct, except that in theory there can be THREE different headers/section. By default there is only one: the PRIMARYHeaderFooter. But also possible are FIRSTPAGE and EVEN when those options have been activated for the section, respectively the entire document.

Comment: This is why Word uses *field codes* for page numbering, the fields are designed to know how to work correctly in the header/footer. Your question was about *inserting* page numbers: your use OOXML to write a PAGE field to the content. *Reading* them in the closed document is not possible since the result is generated dynamically *by the Word application* when the document is opened and *repaginated*. Unlike a page layout file type (such as PDF), Word's content is constantly re-calculated dynamically, which is great for WYSIWYG during editing. But the info isn't retained in the closed file.

Comment: Thank you so much @Cindy for your explaination! I get your point, but still how can I write a PAGE field to content via OOXML? Yea, we are back to the start again, its not like that im not doing any research but I trully cant find any relevant document explaining this :( So far I only know that I can use insertOOXML method to handle ooxml file. Tried, failed...

Answer (score 1):

I finally found time to research and put this together. This code is written ScriptLab. Since ScriptLab complains about XML code that's broken into lines, the XML in the code snippet is all on one line. I've pasted it in formatted form below the code for better readability so that it's possible to see how the Word Open XML is structured.

To get this Word Open XML I saved a Word document with a PAGE field. I then removed all the unnecessary XML, as outlined in the article [Create better add-ins for Word with Office Open XML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/word/create-better-add-ins-for-word-with-office-open-xml).

Note that it's not necessary to type the XML into your code. It can also be saved in a file (note the instructions in the article about referencing XML in a file) or generated using a tool such as the Open XML SDK for Javascript.

**JS in ScriptLab**

```
$("#run").click(() => tryCatch(run));

async function run() {
    // Writes a PAGE field to the primary document header
    await Word.run(async (context) => {
        let sXml = '<pkg:package xmlns:pkg="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/xmlPackage"><pkg:part pkg:name="/_rels/.rels" pkg:contentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-package.relationships+xml" pkg:padding="512"><pkg:xmlData><Relationships xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/relationships"><Relationship Id="rId1" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/officeDocument" Target="word/document.xml"/></Relationships></pkg:xmlData></pkg:part><pkg:part pkg:name="/word/document.xml" pkg:contentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document.main+xml"><pkg:xmlData><w:document xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main"><w:body><w:p><w:r><w:fldChar w:fldCharType="begin"/></w:r><w:r><w:instrText xml:space="preserve"> Page </w:instrText></w:r><w:r><w:fldChar w:fldCharType="separate"/></w:r><w:r><w:rPr><w:noProof/></w:rPr><w:t>1</w:t></w:r><w:r><w:fldChar w:fldCharType="end"/></w:r></w:p></w:body></w:document></pkg:xmlData></pkg:part></pkg:package>';

        //console.log("XML: " + sXml);
        let hdr = context.document.sections.getFirst()
            .getHeader("Primary"); //returns Word.Body type
        hdr.insertOoxml(sXml, 'Start');
        await context.sync();
    });
}

/** Default helper for invoking an action and handling errors. */
async function tryCatch(callback) {
    try {
        await callback();
    }
    catch (error) {
        OfficeHelpers.UI.notify(error);
        OfficeHelpers.Utilities.log(error);
    }
}
```

**The XML**

```
<pkg:package xmlns:pkg="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/xmlPackage">
  <pkg:part pkg:name="/_rels/.rels" pkg:contentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-package.relationships+xml" pkg:padding="512">
    <pkg:xmlData>
      <Relationships xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/relationships">
        <Relationship Id="rId1" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/officeDocument" Target="word/document.xml"/>
      </Relationships>
    </pkg:xmlData>
  </pkg:part>
  <pkg:part pkg:name="/word/document.xml" pkg:contentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document.main+xml">
    <pkg:xmlData>
      <w:document xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main">
        <w:body>
          <w:p>
            <w:r>
              <w:fldChar w:fldCharType="begin"/>
            </w:r>
            <w:r>
              <w:instrText xml:space="preserve"> Page </w:instrText>
            </w:r>
            <w:r>
              <w:fldChar w:fldCharType="separate"/>
            </w:r>
            <w:r>
              <w:rPr>
                <w:noProof/>
              </w:rPr>
              <w:t>1</w:t>
            </w:r>
            <w:r>
              <w:fldChar w:fldCharType="end"/>
            </w:r>
          </w:p>
        </w:body>
      </w:document>
    </pkg:xmlData>
  </pkg:part>
</pkg:package>
```

Comment: Thank you @Cindy Meister! I have actually kinda solved the problem. when I insertooxml, I used replace instead of start, because I have a header already, and it works fine and gives the same result as yours. One problem with both our code is that, it doesn't work only on desktop but not online. The output for word online is " Page <#> of <#>",the actual numbers don't show, but it works perffectly fine on desktop.

Comment: I believe it does work, it's just that Word Online can't *show* it to you as it looks on the Desktop. Field codes can't be updated in Word Online (reference https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/field-codes-in-word-online-d8f46094-13c3-4966-98c3-259748f3caf1) and since the Page field needs to dynamically update, all you see is a placeholder. If I run the code in Word Online, then open the document in a desktop version of Word, I see the page number. And if I open a document created in the desktop version with a page number, it also appears "odd" in Word Online.

Comment: I was looking for this man Cindy! Had you told me about it in my other post instead of ghosting me. I needed an example of inserting ooxml into header. Thank you very much! Thumbs up! I'm surprised I'm the first and only one to rate this at the moment.

Comment: @TimothyLaw Glad it helped you - I'd honestly forgotten all about it. As to not responding further to your other question: You need to "ping" people, as I've done for you, here with the @. Otherwise there's no notification that you've responded in comments. As I wrote the Answer you're commenting on, here, I was notified.

Comment: @CindyMeister Ah...I see...learning new things every time. Thanks again, Cindy!