# How to add MergeFiled in word document using Office JavaScript API

Tags: office365, office-js, office-addins

I am working on one document automation solution which uses velocity to merge variables in a word document. An example of how the current word document template looks is listed below.

```
«#set($sheetTitle='Test 1 sheet for templ»
«#set($viewName='Default')»
«#set($map={"c1":"Name"})»
«$!{map.put("c2","Address")}»
«$!{map.put("c3","City")}»
```

We are using MergeField to insert velocity code. When we press Alt+F9 in Microsoft Word the follow code view is displayed:

```
{ MERGEFIELD  "#set($sheetTitle='Test 1 sheet for template 1')"  \* MERGEFORMAT }
{ MERGEFIELD  #set($viewName='Default')  \* MERGEFORMAT }
{ MERGEFIELD  #set($map={\"c1\":\"Name\"})  \* MERGEFORMAT }
{ MERGEFIELD  $!{map.put(\"c2\",\"Address\")}  \* MERGEFORMAT }
{ MERGEFIELD  $!{map.put(\"c3\",\"City\")}  \* MERGEFORMAT }
```

I am trying to create plugin application using Office.js (Office Online) which will help us to generate a similar velocity template with MERGEFIELD capability.

We can create MergeField in VSTO project using **Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.MailMerge**. However, using Office.js I did not find any option to create MergeField. **Can we create Mergefield using Office.js?**

Thanks

Comment: Office JS APIs for Word currently do not support working with field codes - there's nothing in that object model. There are requests for that capability on UserVoice (https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/16473235-adding-field-codes-for-word-using-word-javascript; https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/33776575-add-support-to-read-field-codes-in-the-document-us). Currently, the only way to insert field codes is via the WordOpenXML (the `insertOOXML` method of the `Range` object).

Comment: You may want to see my Answer to another, similar question https://stackoverflow.com/a/51180120/3077495

Comment: I also need to insert field codes using OfficeJS.  I can insert the entire ooxml in the entire document, but calling insertOoxml() on a Range object 
 ie: searchResults.items[i].insertOoxml(TEMPLATE_TAG, 'Replace'); results in an error, which unfortunately is "Error: unknown".  I need to replace a text string with a field code.  When trying to manually edit the xml for the entire doc I've found that the text string can be in a single xml node, or multiple, depending on how the document was created/edited.  Also,  I've found the opposite problem with multiple text strings in a single node.